# Mongoose, virtuals and Schemas

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing a NodeJS (Typescript) with Mongoose and when I try to add a virtual to my schema in one of the ways Mongoose's documentation suggests, I get an error saying that the prop `virtuals` doesn't exist in type `SchemaOptions`. And a correct error, even though the documentation suggests to use it.

This is what I find in the docs:

```js
// That can be done either by adding it to schema options:
const personSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    first: String,
    last: String
  }
}, {
  virtuals: {          //--------> I get the error here
    fullName: {
      get() {
        return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This is what I was trying:

```js
const mySchema = new Schema<MyInterface>(
  {
    someProp: { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "some-collection" },
    myList: { type: [listSchema], required: true, default: [] },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    virtuals: {
      getByType: {
        get: (type: string) => {
          return this.myList.filter((item: Item) => item.type === type);
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

In the other hand, I can set my virtual this way:

```js
mySchema.virtual("getByType").get((type: string) => {
  return this.myList.filter((item: Item) => item.type === type);
});
```

I had to do a few workarounds to sort the issue about not resolving the `this` keyword, but so far I have no problem about it...
The problem is: I use `findOne` and then try to call my virtual `get` with my document, but I get a Type Error saying `Property 'getByType' does not exist on type 'MyInterface & Document<any, any, MyInterface>'`.

Looks like there is a mix of mistake on the documentation and a Typescript problem here.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual is intended to be used by a `Class`. If you want to use it on an `instance`, use [`methods`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) instead.

Virtual

```
mySchema.virtual("getByType").get((type: string) => {
  return this.myList.filter((item: Item) => item.type === type);
});

// Usage
MySchema.getByType(type)
```

Methods

```
mySchema.methods.getByType = function (type, cb) {
  return this.model('MySchema').find({
    myList: { $elemMatch: { type } }, // Fill your logic here
  }, cb)
};

// Usage
const instance = MySchema.findOne();
const result = instance.getByType(type);
```